# PIL Image library load and save changing pixel values

Tags: pytorch, computer-vision, python-imaging-library, image-segmentation, fast-ai

I am currently working on an Image segmentation problem. As part of preprocessing, I'm trying to create mask values for 2 classes [0, 1]. 
While, saving the processed tensor and loading them back produces different mask values.
 My current guess is under the hood PIL normalizing pixel values. 
If so how do I stop it from doing?

I have created below a simple example explaining the same.

```
tensor_img = torch.where(torch.Tensor(250,250,3) > 0, 1, 0)
img_arr = tensor_img.numpy().astype(np.uint8)
np.unique(img_arr, return_counts=True)
```

(array([0, 1], dtype=uint8), array([148148,  39352]))

```
img = Image.fromarray(img_arr) 
img.save("tmp.jpg")

#read saved image
img = PIL.create("tmp.jpg")
tensor(img).unique(return_counts=True)
```

(tensor([0, 1], dtype=torch.uint8), tensor([62288,   212]))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this simple case (only 2 classes), you need to work with `png` and not `jpeg` since `jpeg` is a lossy compression and `png` is lossless.

```py
tensor_img = torch.where(torch.Tensor(250,250,3) > 0, 1, 0)
img_arr = tensor_img.numpy().astype(np.uint8)
np.unique(img_arr, return_counts=True)
```

(array([0, 1], dtype=uint8), array([159189,  28311]))

```py
img = Image.fromarray(img_arr) 
img.save("tmp.png")

#read saved image
img = np.array(Image.open("tmp.png"))
torch.tensor(img).unique(return_counts=True)
```

(tensor([0, 1], dtype=torch.uint8), tensor([159189,  28311]))

For more classes it is preferred to work with color map.